# How can I setup a global DeadlineExceededError handler?

Tags: google-app-engine, error-handling, requesthandler

I'd like to catch and handle DeadlineExceededError so users don't see the standard "Server Error" page that App Engine throws by default.

I know that DeadlineExceededErrors are [not caught when overriding handle_exception](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2110) in your request handler (we already do this).

I have tried, unsuccessfully so far, to use the [custom error_handlers app.yaml configuration](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses) like so:

```
error_handlers:
  - error_code: timeout
    file: timeout.html
```

...but that also doesn't seem to catch DeadlineExceededErrors, unless I'm doing something wrong.

I am aware that I can use the following pattern to catch DeadlineExceededErrors inside particular request handlers:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:
            # Do stuff...
        except DeadlineExceededError:
            # Many Whelps! Handle it!
```

...but I would like to avoid adding this to every single request handler in my application.

How can I globally catch these elusive suckers?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use webapp2, which is a pretty neat framework as it is and has a lot of useful stuff over the original webapp. With webapp2, you can handle the exception in the handle_500 method, as follows:

```
def BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def handle_500(request, response, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, DeadlineExceededError):
            response.write('Deadline exceeded!')
        else:
            response.write('A server error occurred!')

        logging.exception(exception)
        response.set_status(500)
```

Comment: In webapp2, you could set an error handler to handle 500 status code -- mostly used for uncaught exceptions. There, check what type of exception it is and handle accordingly: if isinstance(exception, DeadlineExceededError): ... Docs are here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#exceptions-in-the-wsgi-app

Comment: I actually didn't know that; yes, that would be a more appropriate place to put the error handling.

Comment: This is what I'd suggest. Please, please don't send redirects for errors, though - serve up the error page on the same URL.

Comment: Yes, that was just filler.  I do suppose it makes a bad example, I'll change it.

Comment: @moraes this resembles pretty much what [web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/custom_notfound) does, it's very handy.